# What is the proper word/term/expression to describe a dish that appears to be something different

Tags: molecular-gastronomy

I want to experiment with dishes that fool the senses. Dishes that look like one thing but taste completely different from what was visually expected (e.g. [Heston's parsnip cereal](http://thebigfatundertaking.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/51-parsnip-cereal/))

I want to google for these kinds of recipies, but what seach terms should I use? Is there a term of art or word which describes these dishes?

Comment: A now-legendary [SCA](http://sca.org) event based on this idea was called the Feast of Illusion, if I recall correctly. It was an entire medieval-style dinner where nothing was as it seemed: the sweet dishes looked savory and vice versa, the hard-boiled eggs were actually eggshells stuffed with custard, and so on.

Comment: I think any SCA event that is legendary is legendary within a pretty small community :-)  Perhaps a fun and exciting one, but not a widely known one.

Comment: what's the SCA ...?

Comment: Society for Creative Anachronism.  They recreate historical events the way they *wish* they had been.   That is my best understanding, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the most common term, especially for foods that just visually look like another food, is [Trompe-l'œil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-l%27%C5%93il).  While the Wikipedia article linked focuses on other forms of art, the word is still applied to foods.

If you google "[Trompe l'œil food](https://www.google.com/search?q=Trompe%20l%27%C5%93il%20food)", you will find many examples of the term in use.

Note that Google seems smart enough to handle either "œ" or "oe".

Comment: I suspected that term might be used, but a search of this site of the word "trompe" retuned no results, so I assumed it wasn't widely used in cooking.

Answer (score 3):

The term seems to be **illusion foods**.

They seemed to have been very popular in the middle ages: [Here's a description](http://www.florilegium.org/?http%3A//www.florilegium.org/files/FEASTS/ill-fd-feast-art.html) of the medieval feast I mentioned in a comment. There's also a [chapter on such foods](http://www.godecookery.com/illusion/illusion.html) in an online medieval cookbook. But a quick search also finds [pinterest boards](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpinterest.com%2Fvolscian%2Fillusion-foods%2F&ei=Z6QKUqrfNvS34AOy_YCgBw&usg=AFQjCNEUW9-HET_KB-YHRkcGLl9F8TyVng&bvm=bv.50500085,d.dmg&cad=rja) and [lists](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDgQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshine.yahoo.com%2Fshine-food%2F5-optical-illusion-dishes-163100520.html&ei=Z6QKUqrfNvS34AOy_YCgBw&usg=AFQjCNG45UDp2c-iyANNn1m14xT5V0ibRQ&bvm=bv.50500085,d.dmg&cad=rja) on general-interest websites.

Answer (score 2):

They may under a few terms:

- Mostly under [Faux Food](http://www.cooks.com/rec/search/0,1-0,faux_food,FF.html)
- Also [Fake Out food](http://www.thekitchn.com/good-question-35-75063)
- Also [April Fools Day recipes](http://allrecipes.com/recipes/holidays-and-events/events-and-gatherings/april-fools-day/)
- Sometimes they hide in plain sight and not so searchable.  Like these [Vegan sunny side up Eggs](http://www.instructables.com/id/Vegan-Egg/).